# New line after all loaded items in listbox (C#)

Tags: c#, listbox

So I want something like:

> item1
>
> item2

but I get:

> item1item2

Please help!

My current code:

```
TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("IP.txt");
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    txt.WriteLine("\n" + item.ToString());
    txt.Close();
}

listBox1.Items.Clear();
TextReader reader = new StreamReader("IP.txt");

listBox1.Items.Add("\n" + reader.ReadToEnd());
reader.Close();
```

Comment: I don't get it. Does your text file "IP.txt" has the wrong output or your listbox at the end has only one item?

Comment: When I load the file in the list box it puts all items on one line, but in the text editor it puts items on different lines

Comment: You are adding one item to listbox which is one single string from the file. You should split the string read from the file by "\n" and then add those strings one by one to the listbox.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand, how would I do that? I have got 
            listBox1.Items.Add("\n" + reader.ReadToEnd());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of Reader/Writer but use `File` and let .Net solve the task for you:

Writing to file:

```
File.WriteAllLines("IP.txt", listBox1
  .Items
  .OfType<Object>() 
  .Select(item => item.ToString()));
```

Reading from file:

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();

listBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("IP.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `"\n"`:

```
TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("IP.txt");
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    txt.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + item.ToString());
    txt.Close();
}

listBox1.Items.Clear();
TextReader reader = new StreamReader("IP.txt");

listBox1.Items.Add(Environment.NewLine + reader.ReadToEnd());
reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

See code below. Your original had a couple of bugs:

1. You're closing `txt` inside the loop used to write the listbox items to the text file.
2. You don't need the `\n` in `txt.WriteLine("\n" + item.ToString());`. `WriteLine` provides the newline
3. You need a loop to read the text file and re-add each line back tot he listbox
4. I suggest you use `using` to ensure files are closed and objects are disposed in case the program crashes for some reason

Note:  I added `" text from file"` to the text added back to the listbox to demonstrate that the listbox was loaded from the text file

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Item1");
listBox1.Items.Add("Item2");

 using (TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("IP.txt"))
 {
     foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
     {
         txt.WriteLine(item.ToString());
     }
 }

 listBox1.Items.Clear();

 using (StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("IP.txt"))
 {
     while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
     {
         listBox1.Items.Add(inputFile.ReadLine() + " text from file");
     }
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ReadToEnd() reads all characters from the current position to the end of the text reader and returns them as one string. Instead use this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("IP.txt");
```

This will have all your lines. You can now iterate on the array and create list box items.

Comment: taught me something - Good to know - I'll keep that in mind